# Django Migrate issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

A django model created as follows

```
from django.db import models

class Vender(models.Model):
    id  =models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        db_table="vendor"

class car(models.Model):
    id  =models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Vender=models.ForeignKey(Vender)
    carmodel =models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        db_table="car"
```

Initially `makemigration` and `migrate` worked fine. Then I changed some model fields and options.
After that getting the below error. I am new to Django.
This kind of issues is happen in production how we can solve with out effecting live transaction data.

```
F:\Workspace\virtspace\demosrc>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, base, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying base.0003_auto_20150110_2004...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field_by_name(self.name)[0])
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 439, in remove_field
    self.execute(sql)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 99, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 916, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Which error? There is no error included in your question.

Comment: Initially makemigration and migrate worked fine. Then i changed some model fields and options.
    After that getting the below error. I am new to django and studying django. Production side how we can handle this errors

Comment: Please put all details in the question, the comments is not for extended discussion. As limelights points out - there is no error message in your question, please update it with the full error message (the entire stack trace).

Comment: Did you change the `id` column?

Comment: yes first the pk field is name and carmodel respectively. Because of this error i added id column

Answer (score 0):

you dont need

```
id  =models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

django adds it for you. dont worry about it.

delete these fields, `makemigrations`, `migrate` and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok to keep

```
id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

I have faced this issue several times, the solution what i use is , before change the field of an existing model, run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --appName
python manage.py migrate --appName --fake
```

then make field changes in the model, run following:
 
 `python manage.py makemigrations --appName
 python manage.py migrate --appName`

U will see all a green result!

Then reason for it because:
When u run `makemigrations --appName` u may will get something like:
    
    `Migrations for 'app':
  0001_initial.py:
    -Create model Vender
    - Create model car`

But actually u have already create these two model when u first create the db, so just migrate in fake way, it will do nothing but keep the initial file. Then make change, run migrate again, the system will detective the changes automatically